# Group records to a single records for each where multiple columns can have multiple values

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

```
NAME      COLUMN1  COLUMN2  COLUMN3
john      n        n        y
jane      y        n        n
jane      n        n        y
jane      n        y        n
jack      y        n        n
jack      n        y        n
```

---

```
What would like to see:
john     n         n        y
jane     y         y        y
jack     y         y        n
```

---

I searched...I really did but probably was not using the correct terms.  Thanks for any help.  The solution is probably simple but I can't get these records grouped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to want `max()`:

```
select name, max(column1) as column1, max(column2) as column2, max(column3) as column3
from t
group by name;
```

Comment: Please take a moment to mark this as your accepted answer by clicking the gray check mark to the left of the answer. It lets other users know the question has an answer, and rewards the user who answered with some reputation points; and you get some, too.